# API RestFul do PagSeguro retornando "message": "Unauthorized"?

Tags: postman

Estou tentando implementar o pagamento por cartão usando a API Rest do PagSeguro. Segui todos os passos desta [documentação](https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v4.0/reference/cobranca-criando-uma-cobranca) mas o retorno é sempre `"message": "Unauthorized"`. Estou testando diretamente no POSTMAN

Como resolver isso ?

```
//url:  https://sandbox.api.pagseguro.com/charges
//token: "jkerjhelajkrhqleubbc...."

//headers
//Content-Type: application/json
//Authorization: {{token}}
//x-api-version: "1.0"
//x-idempotency-key: ""

//json
{
  "reference_id": "823",
  "description": "Compra de produtos site",
  "amount": {
    "value": 1000,
    "currency": "BRL"
  },
  "payment_method": {
    "type": "CREDIT_CARD",
    "installments": 1,
    "capture": true,
    "card": {
      "number": "4111111111111111",
      "exp_month": "03",
      "exp_year": "2026",
      "security_code": "123",
      "holder": {
        "name": "Jose da Silva"
      }
    }
  },
  "notification_url": "https://meusite.com/StatusPagamentoTransaction"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, esses processos de integração necessitam de um passo chamado autenticação, que é onde você se identifica e gera seu acesso para os serviços.

Essa doc aqui deve te ajudar: https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v4.0/docs/api-autenticacao

Após gerar o token, vc precisa adicionar ao header da sua requisição.

o/

Comment: O que vc esta dizendo é que devo ter um token para sandbox e um para a produção ?  O de produção eu ja tenho, mas o de sandbox não estou conseguindo pq esta fora do ar. Veja o link https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/

Comment: Isso, é necessário um token para o SandBox também.